# How to return a normal javascript date object?

Tags: eonasdan-datetimepicker

Is it possible to return a javascript date object from this? I have an text input field with the calendar and want to return a standard date object from it's value... Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
var date = '2016-06-12'; // Can be document.getElementById('myField').value that points to your date field.
var date_parts = date.split('-');
var date_obj = new Date(date_parts[0],date_parts[1],date_parts[2]);
console.log(date_obj);
```

You can also simply use

```
new Date(document.getElementById('myField').value)
```

and see if it works. The date function is smart enough to parse based on browser's locale. This should work for time as well. Eg. `new Date('2016-06-12 04:15:30')`

Comment: Amazing thank you! Does your knowledge extend to being able to help me with the time aswell, i.e. when then value is '06/09/2016 12:42 PM'.

Not to worries if not but I thought I would ask!

Comment: Try this `console.log(new Date('2016-06-12 04:15:30'));`